# how to access object property using variable

Tags: javascript, variables, object, properties

I have an object

```
var Messages = {
'fullName' : 'Tell us your cool name dude..! e.g. Yousuf Iqbal',
'userName' : 'Choose a catchy username. Remember! It should be available :)',
'password' : 'Choose a top secret password with special chars, numbers and alphabets',
'rePassword' : 'Retype the password you just typed. But, don\'t try to copy!',
'bYear' : 'Tell the year, in which this bomb blasted'
};
```

and a variable..

```
var attribute = $('#userinfo form input').attr('name');
```

now i want to select Messages object property using this variable like this..

```
var message = Messages.attribute;
```

but Its not working..
and have also tried the following..

```
var message = Messages+'.'+attribute;
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Square brackets:

```
message = Messages[ attribute ];
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var message = Messages[attribute];
```