# Javascript / Jquery - Get an object properties by it's name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently writing my own small templating engine in javascript.

Here's how a template would look like:

```
<!-- Defines the template for the ribbon. -->
{{TMPL:Import=tabs.tmpl; Name=Tabs}}
<div id="{{ribbonId}}" class="ribbon">

    <!-- All the different tabs are being rendered here. -->
    {{Render:Tabs}}
</div>
```

You might see that in the id of the div element, I would like to render the value of ribbonId of my object.

Now, I have an object ribbon, which is defined as following:

var ribbon = { ribbonId: "mainRibbon" }

Now, how can I get on this object the value of ribbonId, by it's name?

So, the templating engine would request something like:

```
var templateName = ribbonId;
alert(ribbon.templateName);
```

In the alert, I would like to receive 'mainRibbon'.

Is something like this possible in Javascript or jQuery?

Kind regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256091/how-to-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use dot notation when variable is used as key, you need to use bracket notation, instead of :

```
alert(ribbon.templateName);
```

do

```
var ribbon = { ribbonId: "mainRibbon" };
var templateName = "ribbonId"; //string
alert(ribbon[templateName]);
```

demo:: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ueP4h/)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactely which I'm looking for.

Comment: I've did it, I wasn't able to accept (needed to wait a couple of more minutes) but now the time has passed :-)