# Not able to get JSON data by javascript

Tags: jquery, json

I am using each method to get data.

```
$('#gridDetails th').each(function(index, element) {
            var head = $(this).html();
            console.log(head);
            var data = datas[0].head;
            console.log(data);
            var div = $('<div>'+head+'</div><div>'+data+'</div>');
            console.log(div);
            $('#gridDetails').append(div);
        });
```

head has symbol & Price
Here head are shown. But data not able to get. and  when we are use datas[0].symbol, It shows correctly

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256091/how-to-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: `$(element).html()` not `$(this).html()`

Comment: Try `datas[0]['head']`

Comment: use `[]` notation `datas[0][head]`. No quotes around `head` as @Smartik has shown

Comment: var data = datas[0][head] It is working fine. Thanks a lot