# Not able to get JSON value dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am working on the following snippet. Why am I not able to get the

```
let node = 'Em2';
console.log(data.node.c2);
```

work? As you can see I am able to get data while passing `data.Em2.c1` but a dynamic format like this `let node = 'Em2'; console.log(data.node.c2);` I am getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'c2' of undefined

Code:

```
var data ={
   "Em1": { "c1":"#FFF", "c2":"#EEE" },
   "Em2": { "c1":"#DDD", "c2":"#ooo" }
}


let node = 'Em2';

console.log(data.Em2.c1);
console.log(data.node.c2);
```

```js
var data ={
   "Em1": { "c1":"#FFF", "c2":"#EEE" },
   "Em2": { "c1":"#DDD", "c2":"#ooo" }
}


let node = 'Em2';

console.log(data.Em2.c1);
console.log(data.node.c2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use square braces `[]` to [access object member via variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```js
var data ={
   "Em1": { "c1":"#FFF", "c2":"#EEE" },
   "Em2": { "c1":"#DDD", "c2":"#ooo" }
}


let node = 'Em2';

console.log(data.Em2.c1);
console.log(data[node].c2);
```

Similar question: [how to access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256091/how-to-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Thanks Alex but why `[]` ?!

Comment: @Mona if you don't use square braces, js tries to use named property `node`  in your object, not property named in variable `node`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `console.log(data.node.c2)`, try `console.log(data[node][c2])`